# Let $R$ be a $\mathbb Z$ graded ring and let $f \in R_1$ where $f \ne 0$. Show that $R[f^{-1}]$ is a $\mathbb Z$ graded ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization, graded-rings

I've defined $R[f^{-1}]_i = \{ \frac{r}{f^k} \mid r \in R_{i+k}\}$ and I've shown that each $R[f^{-1}]_i$ is an abelian group.

I've shown that $R[f^{-1}]_i R[f^{-1}]_j \subset R[f^{-1}]_{i+j}$.

I just need to show that $R[f^{-1}]$ is a direct sum of the $R[f^{-1}]_i$.

If $\frac{r}{f^k} \in R[f^{-1}]$, then $r \in R$ can be written uniquely $r=r_a + \cdots + r_{a+n}$ where $a \in \mathbb Z$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.

So, $\frac{r}{f^k} = \frac{r_a + \cdots + r_{a+n}}{f^k} = \frac{r_a}{f^k}+\cdots + \frac{r_{a+n}}{f^k} \in R[f^{-1}]_{a-k} + \cdots + R[f^{-1}]_{a+n-k}$.

So, $R[f^{-1}]$ is a sum of the $R[f^{-1}]_i$.

**How can we show $R[f^{-1}]$ is a direct sum of the $R[f^{-1}]_i$?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** : multiply any relation $\sum_i \frac{r_i}{f^{k_i}} = 0$ in $R[f^{-1}]$ by a sufficiently large power of $f$ to get a relation *in $R$*.

Comment: I'm not sure this is sufficient. Consider $\frac{r_0}{f^3}+\frac{r_2}{f^5} =0$. Then $\frac{f^5r_0 + f^3r_2}{f^8} =0$. So, for some $k$, we have $f^k(f^5r_0 + f^3r_2)=0$. So, $f^{5+k}r_0 + f^{3+k}r_2=0$. Since these elements have the same degree, we cannot conclude that $r_0=r_2=0$.

Comment: I think we must have $\deg (r_j / f_{k_j}) \ne \deg ( r_\ell / f_{k_\ell})$ for $j \ne \ell$.

Comment: Well yes, of course : if $r_j/f_{k_j}$ and $r_l/f_{k_l}$ have the same degree, they live in the same $R[f^{-1}]_i$, where $i$ is that degree ! So of course you have to assume they have different degrees : when proving a sum $\sum_i A_i$ is direct, you assume $\sum_i r_i = 0$ with $r_i\in A_i$